# How does a restriction on the domain of an integral change upon doing one of the integrals?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, integral-domain, multiple-integral

I have a complicated integral which schematically looks like
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{-1}^1\mathop{dt}\int_0^{\infty}\mathop{dx}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathop{d\phi}    f(\phi,x,t), \tag{1}    
\end{equation}
where the function $f$ is too complicated to write down here.

In addition to the bounds given on the integral, there is a restriction on the domain of integration
\begin{equation}
\vert \cos{\phi} \vert \leq x\sqrt{1-t^2}, \tag{2} \label{eq2}
\end{equation}
which you could think of as being enforced by a step function times the integrand.

Say we integrate out $\phi$ first, successfully taking into account the restriction \ref{eq2} .  What does Eq. \ref{eq2} become after doing that integral?

If this was just a triple integral in cartesian coordinates, you could just set the integrated-out variable ($\phi$ in this case) to zero to derive the new condition on the remaining integral, but I believe it might be different here because the coordinate system is more complicated, since $\phi$ is an angular variable.

Comment: Although physically this is an integral in spherical coordinates, mathematically it's just a 3-variable integral. As long as you don't forget your Jacobian factor, it's no different from a cartesian one.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Sure, that seems reasonable.  So just as in a triple integral in cartesian, where we project the constraint down to the $xy$ plane after doing the $z$ integral, we can now project this integral domain by setting $\phi=0$, and (2) becomes $1\leq x\sqrt{1-t^2}$?